# JWT Computing the Signature SHA256withRSA

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to

> Sign the UTF-8 representation of the input using SHA256withRSA (also
>   known as RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5-SIGN with the SHA-256 hash function) with
>   the private key obtained from the API console. The output will be a
>   byte array.

so let's take Header and Claim set and put them into array

```
{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}.
{
  "iss":"761326798069-r5mljlln1rd4lrbhg75efgigp36m78j5@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
  "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction",
  "aud":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "exp":1328554385,
  "iat":1328550785
}
```

just like [Service Account: Computing the Signature](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#computingsignature)

> JSON Web Signature (JWS) is the specification that guides the
>   mechanics of generating the signature for the JWT. **The input for the signature is the byte array** of the following content:
>
> {**Base64url encoded** header}.{**Base64url encoded** claim set}

so I build array just to test that

```
  $seg0 = array(
    "alg" => "RS256",
    "typ" => "JWT"
  );
  $seg1 = array(
    "iss" => "761326798069-r5mljlln1rd4lrbhg75efgigp36m78j5@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
    "scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction",
    "aud" => "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "exp" => 1328554385,
    "iat" => 1328550785
  );

  $segs = array(
    json_encode($seg0),
    stripslashes(json_encode($seg1))
  );
  $segments = array(
    rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($segs[0]), '+/', '-_'), '='),
    rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($segs[1]), '+/', '-_'), '='),
  );
```

Here it is. THe first 2 arrays encode successful.

```
Output
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9
eyJpc3MiOiI3NjEzMjY3OTgwNjktcjVtbGpsbG4xcmQ0bHJiaGc3NWVmZ2lncDM2bTc4ajVAZGV2ZWxvcGVyLmdzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC5jb20iLCJzY29wZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lmdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29tL2F1dGgvcHJlZGljdGlvbiIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYWNjb3VudHMuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS9vL29hdXRoMi90b2tlbiIsImV4cCI6MTMyODU1NDM4NSwiaWF0IjoxMzI4NTUwNzg1fQ
```

I go forward and encode the signature

> The signature must then be Base64url encoded. The signature is then
>   concatenated with a ‘.’ character to the end of the Base64url
>   representation of the input string. The result is the JWT. It should
>   be the following:
>       {**Base64url encoded** header}.{**Base64url encoded** claim set}.{**Base64url encoded** signature}

```
  $signature = makeSignedJwt($segments);
  //$signature = makeSignedJwt($segs);
  echo $signature .'<br /><br />';
  $segments[] = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($signature), '+/', '-_'), '=');
  echo '<pre>'; print_r($segments); echo '</pre>';  

function makeSignedJwt($segments)
{
    $data = implode('.', $segments);
    if (!openssl_sign($data, $signature, privateKey, "sha256"))
    {
        exit("Unable to sign data");
    }
    return $signature;
}

Output
    Array
(
    [0] => eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9
    [1] => eyJpc3MiOiI3NjEzMjY3OTgwNjktcjVtbGpsbG4xcmQ0bHJiaGc3NWVmZ2lncDM2bTc4ajVAZGV2ZWxvcGVyLmdzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC5jb20iLCJzY29wZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lmdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29tL2F1dGgvcHJlZGljdGlvbiIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYWNjb3VudHMuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS9vL29hdXRoMi90b2tlbiIsImV4cCI6MTMyODU1NDM4NSwiaWF0IjoxMzI4NTUwNzg1fQ
    [2] => xFS6iZdJku5RKJ5_XdH3W5A8e9V3wsaFeQhAXoJtuxzW-xvqZq1CdEJJAo60VvK1UFONElVf_pthezEyz-eyWsoRGVZFibUQBaKXLI8eR28eFlaCAKH7bKh820uR7IwuRx4xr8MPmnC8so9u9TEY153gkU6Mz9e--pQPlcLlGY
)
```

Must be missing something..

Comment: Hello, where is your question? Is your signed data incorrect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is, but the following worked for me:

```
//helper function
function base64url_encode($data) { 
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '='); 
}

//Google's Documentation of Creating a JWT: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests

//{Base64url encoded JSON header}
$jwtHeader = base64url_encode(json_encode(array(
    "alg" => "RS256",
    "typ" => "JWT"
)));
//{Base64url encoded JSON claim set}
$now = time();
$jwtClaim = base64url_encode(json_encode(array(
    "iss" => "761326798069-r5mljlln1rd4lrbhg75efgigp36m78j5@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
    "scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction",
    "aud" => "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
    "exp" => $now + 3600,
    "iat" => $now
)));
//The base string for the signature: {Base64url encoded JSON header}.{Base64url encoded JSON claim set}
openssl_sign(
    $jwtHeader.".".$jwtClaim,
    $jwtSig,
    $your_private_key_from_google_api_console,
    "sha256WithRSAEncryption"
);
$jwtSig = base64url_encode($jwtSig);

//{Base64url encoded JSON header}.{Base64url encoded JSON claim set}.{Base64url encoded signature}
$jwtAssertion = $jwtHeader.".".$jwtClaim.".".$jwtSig;
```

Comment: It's been awhile.. Anyway from what I remember(if I remember correct) was solved with help of google-api php library but I find your answer much preferable. Thanks