# How to create Service Account in new Google Cloud console?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

The Google cloud console seems to have changed. I am unable to create a service account under the new console. There are 5 options available on the new console:

1. Web application
2. Android
3. iOS
4. Chrome
5. Native

But I am unable to find the service account option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the following answer from a few days ago - this option has recently moved:  [google oauth2 how to get private key for service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413139/google-oauth2-how-to-get-private-key-for-service-account)