# Node.js oauth2 module for headless retrieval of access token

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api

I know I have run across this before but I cant seem to find it anymore.
Does there exist a Node.js module that will allow the retrieval of a Google API access token without a browser?
I would like to make authenticated requests to the Google API on a headless server.  The modules that I am finding however all require a browser.
Does there exist a module where all of this could be handled on the server entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish your server to act on its own behalf (that is, not access the Google API on behalf of a user logged into your application) then this is achieved by creating a service account in the Google Developer Console ([google oauth2 how to get private key for service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413139/google-oauth2-how-to-get-private-key-for-service-account)) and using the Google API node.js Client (https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/).

See the following for an example of how to use Google Cloud Datastore from a node.js application - the authentication principles are the same for other Google APIs:
https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_nodejs/