# How to create Service Account for Google Analytic

Tags: oauth, google-analytics

I'm trying to create a new Service Account to access API data but the options are:

- Web application
- Android
- Chrome App
- iOS
- PlayStation 4
- Other

It was previously answered here but now the options don't include "Service Account":
[google oauth2 how to get private key for service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413139/google-oauth2-how-to-get-private-key-for-service-account)

Here are the instructions from Google's page (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py#clientId)

Create a client ID

From the Credentials page, click Create new Client ID under the OAuth heading to create your OAuth 2.0 credentials.

- For the APPLICATION TYPE select Service account.
- Click Create Client ID.
- For the KEY TYPE select P12 key.
- A dialog box appears. To proceed, click Okay, got it.

Comment: The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py#clientId) has been updated since you posted. The short answer to your question is to go to the [Service account section](https://console.developers.google.com/projectselector/permissions/serviceaccounts) of developer console and click `Create service account`. When prompted for a key type be sure to select `P12`

Comment: Matt, does that mean the required email address is now different? I am getting: <projectId>-<uniqueId>@yuk-uda.iam.gserviceaccount.com, previously they required: <projectId>-<uniqueId>@developer.gserviceaccount.com