# Unable to create google cloud service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have followed the steps detailed here: [google oauth2 how to get private key for service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413139/google-oauth2-how-to-get-private-key-for-service-account)

But everytime i try and create a service account the process fails. The error message is an unhelpful "Sorry, there’s a problem. If you entered information, check it and try again. Otherwise, the problem might clear up on its own, so check back later."

I have waited a full 24 hrs and the problem has persisted. Can someone please help.

Edit: I want to create a p12 key but i have tried generating both json and p12

Comment: Is it possible to provide a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: @Vilas [Here](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2hwo979&s=9#.Vp56CCEvC00) is a screenshot. But its mostly unhelpful. The message is the same as the I've mentioned in post.